# How to create a textbox like navigation box in IE9

Tags: c#, wpf

I sure you ever look navigation box of IE9.
in that textbox there is a combobox, and 3 button-like.
Please help me create a textbox like that using xaml and c#.
please....

Comment: They're all separate controls placed into a toolbar window. I don't know how that translates to WPF. Does it have a wrapper for the Win32 toolbar control and toolbar buttons? The combo box is simple to implement; just put two buttons next to it, and you've got the whole effect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about IE9's navigation buttons in the address bar, there's no trick behind this. Just place the other controls (buttons, icons or whatever) above the dropdown box.

This can also be noticed if you have a closer look at the address bar's coloring of URLs:

Without mouseover the domain is black, other parts of the URL are grey. While the mouse hovers the bar everything is in black.
Try the same thing while being above the buttons and you'll notice this isn't happening (except tinting the background white; which is quite buggy when moving the mouse up/down several times).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a special template for each of the controls that I wanted to enclose in such a combination, such that they do not have a border; also make them have a non-zero margin, a transparent background, and they have hot-track effects. (Make sure you template the dropdown menus so they DO have borders and a background, though.) Then I would put controls using those templates inside a 2-column Grid inside a Border object, with column width settings such that the right edge of the ComboBox gets pushed left when new buttons are added. The buttons would live in a StackPanel in the rightmost Grid column. This approach prevents you from having to maintain a custom control.